# WordPress: displaying a list of posts in `edit` page of admin panel (meta box) cause all fields empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in my WordPress that authors will send new posts in it. I want to display a list of posts in "Edit" page of that custom post type in admin panel.

So I created a meta box and used a code to get posts from another custom post type (it suppose to be such a quick posts that i had to add it).

Meta box added fine, posts getting fine, but when i enter edit page, another custom fields (Advanced custom fields) will fully clear and empty! When I remove that post's list code, field's data will show but when i add getting post's code, it will clear fields data.

this is code for getting posts list:

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $_GET['post'];

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'vosooli', 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'parvande_id_invosolli','value' => $post_id,),), );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    
    <?php $post_idm = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <?php $vaziat_vosoolyi = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vosooli_status', true); ?>

    <a status="<?php echo $vaziat_vosoolyi; ?>" class="listvosoole vosoolshode" href="https://example.com/vosooli-info.php?id=<?php echo $post_idm; ?>" >
        <?php $mablaaq = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vosooli_mablaq', true); echo number_format($mablaaq, 0, '.', ','); ?>
        <span><?php echo $vaziat_vosoolyi; ?></span>
    </a>
    
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I think there is a problem to end postdata and end query and let page to continue loading fields data like `wp_reset_postdata();` etc. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid altering the global $post variable within the admin context. Instead, you can use a custom `WP_Query` or `get_posts` without setup_postdata

```
global $post;
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ?? 0; // Ensure you have a default value

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'vosooli',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'parvande_id_invosolli',
            'value' => $post_id,
        ),
    ),
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
    $post_idm = $mypost->ID;
    $vaziat_vosoolyi = get_post_meta($mypost->ID, 'vosooli_status', true);
    ?>
    
    <a status="<?php echo esc_attr($vaziat_vosoolyi); ?>" class="listvosoole vosoolshode" href="https://example.com/vosooli-info.php?id=<?php echo esc_attr($post_idm); ?>">
        <?php
        $mablaaq = get_post_meta($mypost->ID, 'vosooli_mablaq', true);
        echo esc_html(number_format($mablaaq, 0, '.', ','));
        ?>
        <span><?php echo esc_html($vaziat_vosoolyi); ?></span>
    </a>
    
    <?php
}

// No need to reset post data as we didn't set it up
```